# google login does not work in published Web Site ASP.Net MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, google-signin

I really need some help here. My google login works in the localhost but does not work on published website. I have added the URL in Google API Control Panel.

URL added in Google Panel: `https://www.connect.companyname.com`

**Error: redirect_uri_mismatch**

LocalHost: When I click on google icon below URL gets generated and everything works as expected

**[Working URL Encoded]**

```
         https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?continue=https://accounts.google.com/o/oaut
h2/auth?response_type%3Dcode%26client_id%*****CLIENT ID******.apps.googleusercontent.com%26
         redirect_uri%3Dhttp://localhost:5271/Security/LoginSettingsSubmit%26scope%3Dopenid%2Bemail
    %26%26from_login%3D1%26as%3D-1004f53b4f4074a4&ltmpl=embedded&btmpl=authsub&scc=1&oauth=1
```

**[Working URL Decoded]**

```
    https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?continue=https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2
/auth?response_type=code&client_id=***** ClientID***.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost:5271/Security/LoginSettingsSubmit&scope=openid+email&&from_login=1&as=-6396ecb83b38f7e2&ltmpl=embedded&btmpl=authsub&scc=1&oauth=1
```

Published WebSite:

**[NOT WORKING]URL**

Generated as click on Google Icon

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=**ClientID**.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fconnect.companyname.com%3a3382%2fSecurity%2fLoginSettingsSubmit&scope=openid%20email&
```

**Everything works properly in LocalHost**

BackEnd Code in ASP.net MVC 5

```
 public static string UrlForGoogleAuth
        {
            get
            {
                UrlHelper url = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);

                string host = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;
                if (host == "localhost")
                {
                    host = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority;
                }

                string result = "https://" + host + url.Action("LoginSettingsSubmit", "Security");

                return result;
            }
        }
```

**JS**

```
 var ClientID = "****.apps.googleusercontent.com";
        var url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?";
        var parameters = "response_type=code&client_id=".concat(ClientID).concat("&redirect_uri=@(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(SimUtils.UrlForGoogleAuth))" + "&scope=openid%20email&");
        var loginUri = url.concat(parameters);
 window.open(loginUri);
```

BackEnd

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult LoginSettingsSubmit(SimSettingsLoginMV userData)
        {
            UserMV authenticatedUser = null;

            userData.Validate(ModelState);

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                switch (userData.LoginType)
                {
                  
                    case LoginTypeEnum.Google:
                        authenticatedUser = SecurityHelper.AuthenticateUser(userData.GoogleCode, SimUtils.UrlForGoogleAuth, userData.LoginType);
                        break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: when did you add your published/live site to G console for the selected ClientID? It could just be timing...

Comment: atleast 3 months before..

Comment: can you kindly see my published URL once. is that okey?

Comment: Localhost works flawlessly..

Comment: If you do not have any query string values I don't think you need to encode the url. That being said, the encoded url for localhost and the live one that you shared is somewhat strange. I cannot comment on why it would result differently with the same code.

Comment: Can you kindly tell me whats strange and simplify my URL if possible?

Comment: I swear it works in localhost.

Comment: Ya..I believe you mate. It's not that it's a error/issue with what you've done. I'm still not sure why it generated 2 different results for localhost and the LIVE . Get rid of this encoding here `redirect_uri=@(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(SimUtils.UrlForGoogleAuth))` and just go `redirect_uri=@SimUtils.UrlForGoogleAuth` .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131284/discussion-between-unbreakable-and-searching).

Comment: FRESH LOCAL HOST URL: `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=****.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https://localhost:5271/Security/LoginSettingsSubmit&scope=openid%20email&`

Comment: LIVE URL: `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=****.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https://connect.companyname.com:3382/Security/LoginSettingsSubmit&scope=openid%20email&`